# What Actionscript features do not work on iOS?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

There seems to be a lot of conflicting information out there. It might be that support has increased recently, or changes to adobe.com/air have made some information difficult to find - but I can't track down a definitive list of things to avoid.

I know that actionscript won't run in loaded SWFs, I know that some people say that filters and blendmodes and halo components won't work. I've also read many posts saying they will (at least that blendmodes will, and that halo *will* run, but *slowly* so still use spark)

I have a large amount of AS3 code to plan for upgrading to work on iOS, but at the moment I have no idea what things will break (or what things will break when those things have been fixed!)

Is there a list of unsupported APIs, or iOS dos and don'ts?

Thanks

:S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, yes. Externally loaded SWF's will not run. You can however embed SWF's/SWC's into your project and include them inside of your package.

As far as Flex components, stay away from Halo. You should use Flex 4.6 and stick to components with mobile skins. I recommend downloading Tour de Flex http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html to get an idea of whats available.

As far as blend modes go, I'm not really sure. I haven't used them in mobile yet. However filters are supported but they are expensive. For drop shadows on rectangles there is something called RectangularDropShadow. This is actually a component and therefor less expensive. However it can only be used on rectangular groups.

You should have access all of the AIR API's. You will however be restricted when using some of File related classes since I don't believe you can leave your Appliaction Storage Directory.

One big performance tip I can give is to use AS3 over MXML whenever possible, ESPECIALLY when creating item renderers. Use BitmapImage over Image whenever possible, again especially in item renderers. Use cacheAsBitmap whenever you have images that don't change often. And stay away from any Flex component that doesn't have a mobile skin.

You may also want to read up on View and destruction policies.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-development-tips-tricks-pt1.html

This link also has some more performance tips
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-performance-checklist.html

Comment: Thanks. This backs up a lot of what I'm seeing elsewhere. The mobile performance checklist is really useful.

Do you have any more information about MXML? I'm hearing that MXML isn't a problem, but halo components are.

Comment: MXML compiles to AS3, it's more or less a shorthand for as3 classes. Custom components written in AS3 tend to perform better. This video has some good information on writing list item renderers in as3. http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/create-itemrenderers-for-flex-mobile-projects/

Also, if you find this answer satisfactory, please mark it as correct!